# How can I get structuremap to inject a specific instance given a specific requesting class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I thought I had this figured out with the object model, but apparently I keep piecing bits together improperly.  "queueName" is a Func in the parent method, which is just returning a string ultimately.

I'm adding dependencies with the following:

```
conf.For<IMessageQueueFactory<TQueue>>()
    .Use<MicrosoftMessageQueueFactory<TQueue>>()
    .Named(instanceName)
    .Ctor<string>("path")
    .Is(context => queueName(context.GetInstance<IProjectSettings>()))
    .Ctor<QueueAccessMode>("queueAccessMode")
    .Is(QueueAccessMode.SendAndReceive)
    .Ctor<int>("readTimeoutMilliseconds")
    .Is(60000);

conf.For<IMessageQueueReader<TQueue>>()
    .Use(context => context.GetInstance<IMessageQueueFactory<TQueue>>().CreateMessageQueueReader())
    .Named(instanceName + ".reader");

conf.For<IMessageQueueWriter<TQueue>>()
    .Use(context => context.GetInstance<IMessageQueueFactory<TQueue>>().CreateMessageQueueWriter())
    .Named(instanceName + ".writer");
```

This block of code is called about 6 times with different queue configurations, because for the most part `TQueue` is a different object.  We have a case where `TQueue` is the same (one is an initial production, the other is as an error-handling queue for the other 5 areas), so I need to control which one is injected, which is why the instances are all named.

```
conf.For<IMessageQueueReader<CopiedObject>>()
    .ConditionallyUse(a => a.If(c => typeof(FooEngine).IsAssignableFrom(c.ParentType))
        .ThenIt.Is.TheInstanceNamed("queue.copiedobject.writer"));

conf.For<IMessageQueueWriter<CopiedObject>>()
    .ConditionallyUse(a => a.If(c => typeof(BarEngine).IsAssignableFrom(c.ParentType))
        .ThenIt.Is.TheInstanceNamed("queue.copiedobject.reader"));
```

Every *Engine object I have in this has an IQueueReader and an IQueueWriter being injected.  I'm trying to override just the reader of one engine and the writer of another engine, and let everything else be "defaults".  What am I missing?

EDIT: One thing I'm missing is apparently the error message I get -- which of all things is a "bidirectional reference".  Absolutely nothing about an IMessageQueueReader or IMessageQueueWriter requires anything I'm writing, as those aren't even in the same assembly.  Is it the `c.ParentType` part requiring a partial instantiation?

EDIT2: Changing the overrides to the following code stops the error, but StructureMap isn't using the overridden objects.  It's still using the defaults:

```
conf.ForConcreteType<FooEngine>().Configure
    .Ctor<IMessageQueueWriter<FetchedEmail>>()
    .Is(i => i.TheInstanceNamed("queue.copiedobject.writer"));

conf.ForConcreteType<BarEngine>().Configure
    .Ctor<IMessageQueueReader<FetchedEmail>>()
    .Is(i => i.TheInstanceNamed("queue.copiedobject.reader"));
```